# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (jQuery & jQuery Easing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-easing

I am building out a site. I built out the backend, and now I am doing the front-end. On the front end I have bootstrap, various font awesome icons, and angular. It should also be noted this is a rails app.

I want to add 1 page scroll feature using jQuery & jQuery easing, that is powered by a font-awesome arrow. I am obviously not doing something right, because when used it turns blue (thought maybe it was an "active state" because of the href?), and turns all of the font (everything) on my page blue.

When in chrome's console, I get the error;

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Which is referring to this line (might be arbitrary) in jQuery;

`this.pos = eased = jQuery.easing[ this.easing ](`

Here is the rest of my code;

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="page-scroll" id="arrow"><a href="#clients"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i><a></div>
```

**styles.css**

```
  #arrow {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: grey;
}
```

**main.js**

```
    $(function() {
      $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event){
         $('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: $("#clients").offset().top
         }, 1500);
         event.preventDefault();
     });
  });
```

**application.html.erb (thanks to another SO question, jQuery & jQuery Easing placed under style sheets)**

```
<!-- Easing for Page Scroll -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

When I comment out the div in index, all font goes back to normal (it's blue when it's active). When I click on the button, it takes me to the element I want, but it drops you there, it doesn't have the easing aspect (which is why I am adding easing).

I have searched a fair amount, and I am baffled about this (especially the changing of the text). Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you access those variables in the console to isolate the issue? (window.pos, eased, JQuery.easing, window.easing) Also try debugging that line and check the state of the variables just before the exception is thrown

Comment: You're not closing your <a> tag correctly. It's missing the `/` character

Comment: @jasonscript Thank you! I closed it, and that takes care of the font.

Comment: @LinuxN00b in the console, I can access jQuery.easing.  

window.pos and window.easing both bring up undefined.

Comment: Ah ok, it looks to me like it's a context issue, I would assume that window.easing and window.pos should be attached to the element rather than window. Have you some dodgy context binds or calls? Is there more relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since figured out what causes this.

When this happens, your page cannot find jQuery even though it is being called. To fix this, make sure your page content looks something like this (for rails, all of this would be in **application.html.erb**);

**head**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Good SEO.">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Your Title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS for smaller projects/single page I'll use a CDN -->
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet" type='text/css'>

    <!-- CSS or in assets/stylesheets-->
    <link href="/assets/styles.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

**after closing body & html tags**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js">
</body>    
</html>
```

I've noticed the order has to be jQuery, bootstrap (if you're using it), then jquery.easing.